# iOS simulator keeps rotating

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When testing my app using the `iOS Simulator` I sometimes experience the screen rotating and couple of time when changing views. I wonder if this is a bug with the simulator or something wrong with my code. If I close the simulator down and start again it stops. It is very random.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? If Xcode 6 beta, make sure it's up to date, and if you can reproduce it on another machine, consider [filing a bug](http://radar.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcuts for rotating the simulator are <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>. Is it possible you are pressing these keys accidentally, or perhaps have some app that is pressing those keystrokes?

Comment: No, for me, I'm not touching anything. But it just rotates randomly :0